# IIS URL rewrite rule for https and containing path

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to figure out a url rewrite rule to rewrite http requests into https only when a specific path is accessed like below. I've tried quite a few things that in the test pattern seem as though they should work but it never does.

url accessed: http://example.com/books/test.css

I need to check for the http:// and /books/ to form the proper url below.

url needed: https://example.com/books/test.css

A request of http://example.com/book/test.css should be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the patten in the `<match>` element :

```xml
<rule name="Force HTTPS for /books/" enabled="true">
    <match url="^/books/.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent"
            url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true"  />
</rule>
```

or by adding a new `<condition>`

```xml
<rule name="Force HTTPS for /books/" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/books/.*$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent"
            url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true"  />
</rule>
```

Comment: thanks for this. I opted for the 2nd option. Only thing I had to add was an equal sign after pattern in this line

<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern"^/books/.*$" />

Comment: what is the meaning of `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />` ? i am unaware of iis rewrite rule and that why i asked here